A Sharepoint site that is shared with external users from different organizations, and they can only access and see their own map
A Sharepoint site that is shared with external users from different organizations, and they can only access and see their own map. So the external users can't see or access each other's maps and documents, but they all see the same information on the start page of the site.
Is this possible ?
